# Regular expression to match words and return whole string

Tags: regex

How to write a regular expression that would returned strings that contains 'Hp' regardless whether is it lower or upper case ?

```
Hp B1260dn Mono Laser Printer.
Proposed chemical warehouse- RACKING / CAPEX - 2012/CAR/1220.
parlantes.
Laptop hp 6440 para Andrés Van Cauwenberghe D&M Neuquen.
Modelo: Hp Desktop Optiplex 9010.
```

Expected output

```
Hp B1260dn Mono Laser Printer.
Laptop hp 6440 para Andrés Van Cauwenberghe D&M Neuquen.
Modelo: Hp Desktop Optiplex 9010.
```

Comment: Such basic questions should include your own efforts. What have you tried and what does not work for you? Also, what is the programming language?

Comment: @ThoseWhoAnswered: Don't you understand that this is not a question that should be answered that way? I vote to close and then delete this question unless it is edited.

Comment: @stribizhev, what do you mean by *that way*?

Comment: @ndn: What good answering a  question without explaining what you wrote? OP won't learn anything. More, if the question is closed and deleted, and you got the answer accepted and upvoted 9 times, you will lose all that reputation.

Comment: @stribizhev, is that better?

Comment: @ndn: It looks better now. However, I still insist that OP should show some research effort when asking basic regex questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.*[hH][pP].*
```

- `.*` will match as many characters as possible (zero or more)
- `[xX]` defines a character set, which will match a single `x` or `X`

Or you can use a ignorecase flag, but it's language specific

Comment: Thanks...............